# click on link then page data come in body, url change and chat window not go out

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1, url-routing

Greeting of the Morning !

I am working a web application in which, left side bar and body, has chat module like facebook. My problem is when click on any link of the left side bar then page refresh then chat gone.
I tried then show page without redirecting and change url but **ping chat gone.** I have used nodejs for the chat.

I do want click on link then page data come in body, url change and chat window not go out.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/geturl', function(){
    return view('geturl');
});
```

**geturl.blade.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
        //code for the link action
        return false;
    });
});

$(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

        //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
        $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }});

        //to change the browser URL to the given link location
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }

        //stop refreshing to the page given in
        return false;
    });
});

/* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without page reload*/
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    }});
});
</script>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="/dashboard" rel="tab">menu1</a> |
        <a href="/profile/edit" rel="tab">menu2</a> |
        <a href="/contact-support" rel="tab">menu3</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```